# Engineered wood on staircase

Tags: stairs, engineered-flooring

I understand that I need to use both glue **and** nails for the engineered wood flooring to not fall off the stairs, but how do I hide the nails?

Also which glue and nails are best to use?

Comment: Also, should I use glue and nails for any of flat floor areas, or would floating installation be enough (the surface is completely leveled and flat)?

Comment: Check the instructions on the type of floor you're installing. They will tell you exactly what you need.